# Query database to display the total count of data based on current date and month from multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ssms

If I try to select 2 columns, i get an error message that says, Ambiguous column name 'signed_in'. Name of the tables are UserName and Meeting.   Please help

```
 select count(*) 
 FROM UserName, Meeting 
 where YEAR(signed_in ) = datepart(YEAR, getdate());
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the signed_in column is present in both UserName and Meeting tables. You need to prefix the column with a table name like this:
`UserName.signed_in` or `Meeting.signed_in`

Comment: Yes. I have signed_in in both tables

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, I really appreciate.

I have sorted it out using the following code:

select 
 ( select count(*) from UserName where YEAR(signed_in ) = datepart(YEAR, getdate()) )
+ 
 ( select count(*) from Meeting where YEAR(signed_in ) = datepart(YEAR, getdate()))

and the total count for the both tables display in one column, one row. totaling 7 which represents 5 from UserName table and 2 from Meeting table.